How to deal with huge VM allocation by google chrome?
As usual, Google Chrome (or some JS code in one of the tabs) is trying to allocate an extraordinary amount of virtual memory. Google Chrome crashed. Here is the relevant entry in dmesg (emphasis mine):
Oct 24 09:03:48 computer-name kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 556894 (chrome) 
total-vm:*1222346624kB*, anon-rss:955988kB, file-rss:688kB, shmem-rss:39316kB, 
UID:1000 pgtables:4092kB oom_score_adj:300

1222346624 kB is about 1.2 TiB! I agree that many Google Chrome tabs are open (about 100, I agree, that's too many, will fix that, but that's a separate issue). A casual glance shows that if a tab uses 100 MiB VM on average and even if I have 100 tabs open, that shouldn't be more than 10 GiB.
Besides limiting the number of open Chrome tabs, is there anything else I can do?
Some system details:

Acer laptop with Ubuntu 24.04
13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1355U (12 cores), 16 GB SDRAM
4 GB Swap space

